# Why are some linked frameworks look like a piece of Lego, while others like a toolbox?

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

I just noticed that some of the pods that I added appear as a Lego bricks:

[image]

And some pods appear as toolboxes:

[image]

in the linked libraries and frameworks section. As a whole, all my pods look like this:

[image]

Why is that?

Since the name of the section is "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", I assume that one of the icons represents a framework and the other represents a library? But which is which? And how does Xcode know that it is a framework or a library? I checked the podspecs of the pods but I didn't find anything about frameworks/libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Toolbox** is a standard icon for **CocoaTouchFramework** and it's usually mean that it uses `Foundation` framework.

**White Cube (lego bricks)** means bundle. That can link whatever you need, it can be a pack of Localized.strings (ex: [ZendeskSDK](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_sdk_ios/tree/master/ZendeskSDKStrings.bundle)) or other assets.

Please note that there is a difference between how it's displayed inside `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` or `Embedded Binaries` than it is inside `Finder`.

[image]

And framework to work with both Simulator and Device must be built with different architectures (x86_64) vs (armv7,arm64). And it's handled by Xcode what to take from `.framework`, since you don't need to link it manually against different architecture. So in Xcode point of view, you always have in this section right `.framework` file ready for your architecture, so it can be displayed as toolbox. In your case library `LTHPasscodeViewController` does not contain autobuilding scheme (like `SwiftyJSON` for example). No `xcodeproject` besides demo, classes are not linked to `.xcodeproj`, so it's not created from `CocoaTouchFramework`.

When you select new Project from Xcode and choose `Cocoa Touch Framework` it create project for you. When you don't have a project it's just `bundle` (doesn't matter that has `.framework` extension).