# What are the differences between these pod icons?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Inside my pods project
[image]

I have a list of pods targets with their different icons

[image: Pod Targets]

and every time I install/upload the pods, the blue seems to reset themselves. I have to set the team individually for each one.

[image]

Is there some kind of legend for these icons? Why does the problem only occur with the blue ones?

Comment: Can you show a bit more context? In which part of Xcode did you find these? Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38197461/5133585

Comment: Updated with a broader context. The answer you linked helps, but there are only two. Toolbox and bundle. For the third there is not much more info. However, it is not explained why for bundles (blue icon)  there is a need to set up the team with each update.

Answer (score 1):

The Icons do not have different colors and there is no meaning coded in the color themself.

You can add a new target, and look for the icon, to know what exactly it is. The "blue" lego one is a bundle.
[image]